Combinatorics- What is wrong in this approach

The question is- 
In an examination, a question paper consists of 12 questions divided into two parts i.e., Part 1 and Part 2, containing 5 and 7 questions, respectively. A student is required to attempt 8 questions in all, selecting at least 3 from each part. In how many ways can a student select the questions?  
I know that this can be done in this way- 
Selecting 5 questions from 1st part and 3 questions from 2nd part.
That will be in, 
⁵C₅ × ⁷C₃ = 35 ways. 
Selecting 4 questions from 1st part and 4 questions from 2nd part. 
That will be in 
⁵C₄ × ⁷C₄ = 175 ways.  
And at last Selecting 3 questions from 1st part and 5 questions from 2nd part. 
⁵C₃ × ⁷C₅ = 210 ways.  Total ways = 35 + 175 +210 = 420. But if the student selects 3 questions from 5 questions of 1st part, 3 from 7 question of 2nd part and 2 from the remaining 6 questions of union of 1st and 2nd part then there is a problem. 
If this happens then, 
⁵C₃ × ⁷C₃ × ⁶C₂ = 5250. .
So, what is wrong with this approach? Why is the answer incorrect?

 

Overcouting. Say the student eventually solved questions A,B,C,D from the first part. Then you count them as "choosing A,B,C first and then D as one of the two extras" or "choosing A,B,D first and then C as one of the two extras", etc., etc.

@MichalAdamaszek , I got it now. Thanks

Your second approach counts some 'question selections' more than once, giving an inflated answer.
In particular, if a student chose questions 1,2, and 3 from part 1 and questions 6,7, and 8 from part 2, and then chose to additionally solve questions 4 and 5, this is the same collection of questions as choosing 3,4,5, then 6,7,8, then 1 and 2.
Breaking the possible selections into cases like you showed is one way to avoid this kind of overcounting.
